# How do I unset hook_field_storage_load()?

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to unset `hook_field_storage_load()` and `hook_field_storage_write()` in `hook_module_implements_alter()` without success. Is there any other way to turn off those hooks?

Comment: Are you sure the hook is firing?  That one is weird.

Comment: Thank's MDP, I'm sure, I'm trying to unset mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load(), I'm sure its firing. When I put in `hook_module_implements_alter()` 'dpm($hook);' I see all hooks after clear cache: field_storage_details_alter, field_storage_pre_load, field_storage_info, field_storage_info_alter, but not field_storage_load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** `hook_module_implements_alter()` is not invoked when `mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load()` is needed. You cannot achieve what you are trying.

The function that invokes `hook_field_storage_load()` is [field_attach_load()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/field_attach_load/7), which contains the following code.

```
// Invoke hook_field_storage_load() on the relevant storage backends.
foreach ($storages as $storage => $fields) {
  $storage_info = field_info_storage_types($storage);
  module_invoke($storage_info['module'], 'field_storage_load', $entity_type, $queried_entities, $age, $fields, $options);
}
```

[module_invoke()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/module_invoke/7) calls [module_hook()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/module_hook/7), which contains the following code.

```
  $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  // A
  // If the hook implementation does not exist, check whether it may live in an
  // optional include file registered via hook_hook_info().
  $hook_info = module_hook_info();
  if (isset($hook_info[$hook]['group'])) {
    module_load_include('inc', $module, $module . '.' . $hook_info[$hook]['group']);
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
```

Since [mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!mongodb!mongodb_field_storage!mongodb_field_storage.module/function/mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load/7) is contained in [mongodb_field_storage.module](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!mongodb!mongodb_field_storage!mongodb_field_storage.module/7), your implementation of `hook_module_implements_alter()` will not be called. In fact `function_exists($function)` returns `TRUE` when `$function` is equal to `'mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load'`, and the part of the code after the line marked with `// A` will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So what to do to not hack modules? My goal is the implementation of the custom entity controllers to avoid mysql query. Everything works great, except that `mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load()` contain unnecessary a second time query, because we have already loaded the full node object with fields from mongodb...

Comment: In my understanding, `field_attach_load()` is called from [DrupalDefaultEntityController::attachLoad()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3AattachLoad/7), so should be fine if I'll put in my `CustomNodeController` a `attachLoad()` function with `mymodule_field_attach_load()`, which will be a copy of the original function, with the exception of only `module_invoke($storage_info['module'], 'field_storage_load', ...)`, which will be replaced with my copy of `mongodb_field_storage_field_storage_load()`?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I hope I wrote clearly :)

Comment: As far as I can see, there [6 functions/methods](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/calls/field_attach_load/7) that call `field_attach_load()`. If you are just concerned about the hook being called from the entity controller, you can implement a new entity controller. Remember that in a module you cannot define a function/hook with the same name of a function/hook implemented by another module. In other words, in my module I cannot define `node_load()` because PHP would throw an error about a redefined function.